# Where is UnitTestAssertException defined?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

Trying to catch `UnitTestAssertException` per the advice given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9382707/1399272) (working with Visual C++ 2012).  [The MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.unittestassertexception(v=vs.110).aspx) indicates it is in namespace `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting`, but what header do I need to include?

Comment: That question is asking about C# and that class is managed.

Comment: I see.  Originally confused by the C++ tab in the docs, but the attribute should have tipped me off.  Would you mind posting this as an answer I can accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is defined in Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll
The location of the file depends on the installation and version Visual Studio you are using.
For me it is in the following :

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\

AND

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies